# jquery fancybox not showing overlay correctly

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have fancybox setup on this wordpress site: http://melisayavas.com/web/
When a user click on the bottom link News subscription the ajax pop-up box appears but the overlay doesn't float over the main content.

This is the fancybox code that I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : true,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
});
</script>
```

This is the link that the fancybox AJAX is shouwing: http://melisayavas.com/web/wp-content/themes/murtaugh-HTML5-Reset-Wordpress-Theme-8aa6329/subscribe.html - it's a mailchimp form.

I have no idea why the overlay doesn't work properly...

Comment: Are you using fancyBox version 1 or 2?

Comment: Are you updating the page?  It's really unfair to ask this community to help you while you're still making changes to the demo page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a 404 error on `fancybox_sprite.png`

http://melisayavas.com/web/wp-content/themes/murtaugh-HTML5-Reset-Wordpress-Theme-8aa6329/fancybox_sprite.png

**EDIT:**

Now you have a 404 error on `jquery.fancybox.css`

http://melisayavas.com/web/wp-content/themes/murtaugh-HTML5-Reset-Wordpress-Theme-8aa6329/_/js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.5

**EDIT 2:**

Now your page is working fine.  Nothing to do.

Comment: I'm retarded, sorry for wasting your time. The path to the script was wrong. I fixed it and it's working just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeGrigorita, I think it was the path to your CSS that was the root problem, because if your script path was wrong, you would not have even seen the pop-up.  Please accept/vote my answer or post the solution and accept that.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay. The problem was indeed the path, after I fixed the path, the problem was also fixed. Regarding the images (fancy_sprite.png etc) I could overwrite the fancybox css with the same elements in style.css and !important, so that the path to the images was right. Like I said, a simple problem with paths, that I should have figure out by myself, unfortunately I was too tired. Thanks for the answer :)